# Web-based document merge solution?

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

We are looking for a web-based document merge solution.

Our application is a web-based project management tool built using Xataface - PHP on Windows IIS + mySQL.  We have a function that allows the user to generate a status report in Microsoft Word format based on data in the tool.

Currently this function is implemented using LiveDocX.  We have a status report template, and LiveDocX performs the merge into the template using data from our project management tool.

The main drawback is LiveDocx is web-service based.  We are looking to replace LiveDocX in order to reduce our dependence on the up-time of a third-party web-service that we cannot control.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a web-based document merge solution that I can install on my IIS or PHP based server?

Comment: are you merging to Word 2007/2010 formats or do you need earlier formats as well?

Comment: Hi Otaku.  Word 2007 format would be OK, eariler formats are not required necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

In reading your question, I'm not sure if what you're after is actual mail merge or just simply populating a single Word template server-side. In either case, here are some things to get your started:

- For **mail merge** (multiple document
  results based on multiple records,
  say, from a database), you can use
  either the Open XML SDK for a VS
  solution or access the Open XML
  directly. In that case, these are
  good articles to start with:

  - [Mail Merge in WordProcessingML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/2492.aspx)
  - [Mail Merging with a Custom Client
    Using the Open XML SDK 2.0](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/7708.aspx)
- For direct **single-document**
  population with data, these are good
  libraries that use PHP:

  - [PHP Word](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)
  - [PHP OpenXML API](http://openxmlapi.codeplex.com/) (not incredibly
    mature, but a starting point)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for solution then you can try [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx)
it is a commercial component (not free).